# Why copying a bitmap causes a white background appear

Tags: delphi

I have a code that copies paintbox1 to image1 via bitmap (to another form), but this copying is causing a white background to appear in image1.

How to remove that? there is no white are in paintbox at all, actually the paintbox has a circular drawn area.

```
abitmap := tbitmap.create();
aBitmap.Width := anotherform.PaintBox1.Width;
aBitmap.Height := anotherform.PaintBox1.Height;
BitBlt(aBitmap.Canvas.Handle,
  0,
  0,
  aBitmap.Width,
  aBitmap.Height,
  infoontop.PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle,
  0,
  0,
  SRCCOPY);


  image1.picture.Bitmap := abitmap;
```

Answer (score 4):

A `TPaintbox` control does not store a persistent bitmap in the way that a `TImage` does. A paint box is a control that paints itself on demand, via the `OnPaint` event. This event is triggered when the paint box's parent receives a `WM_PAINT` message. The parent is relevant because the paint box is a non-windowed control and so actually paints onto its parent.

What you need to do is refactor the code so that the `OnPaint` handler simple calls a method to perform the painting. Something like this:

```
procedure TMyClass.DoPaint(Canvas: TCanvas; Width, Height: Integer);
begin
  ....
end;
```

Then in your `OnPaint` handler you do:

```
DoPaint(PaintBox1.Canvas, PaintBox1.Width, PaintBox1.Height);
```

And when you wish to paint to a bitmap you do:

```
DoPaint(Bitmap.Canvas, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
```